# Bootstrap - hover effect only work if navbar is not collapsed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i disable hover effect when the navbar is collapsed ?
I'm really new in web developing things, so please kindly advise me.
Thanks
[image]

*What i mean is to remove hover effects of showing 'Action,Another Action, etc' block when my menu is collapsed or in mobile view.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanframes/hcv0eern/

Comment: pls check my jsfiddle link, the previous link was error, so i put it on comment

Comment: hover effect on 'Tutorial Laravel'?

Comment: yes, i'm learning to make a website using laravel framework, and for the navbar i use bootstrap with hover effect.

Comment: I'm on sure what you mean by "collapsed" , do you mean when the navbar is in mobile view?

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru yes.

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only delete the script in the bottom of your HTML, this code:

```
<script>
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
</script>
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.form-area {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 10px 40px 60px;
  margin: 10px 0px 60px;
  border: 1px solid GREY;
}


/* footer */

.full {
  width: 100%;
}

.gap {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  background: #EDEFF1;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.footer h3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BAC1C8;
  color: #54697E;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 27px;
  padding: 40px 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.footer ul {
  font-size: 13px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #7F8C8D;
}

.footer ul li a {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  display: block;
}

.footer a {
  color: #78828D
}

.supportLi h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: #E3E3E3;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-bottom p.pull-left {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.footer-bottom p.pull-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.payments {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid noHoverNav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header ">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="~/" class="navbar-brand title-link">Tutorial Laravel</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="{{Request::path() == '/' ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="{{Request::path() == 'about' ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li class="{{Request::path() == 'contact' ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- DELET THIS SCRIPT! 

<script>
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
</script>

-->
<!-- end-navigation -->
```

Comment: Check out the updated code, I have deleted the script in the bottom of your HTML.

Comment: Thanks ! This is what i want.